# Is there a reliable broken links check for https websites built with angularjs?

Tags: links, validation

Couldn't really a find a decent broken links checker for https website built with AngularJS!

Mainly tested the following tools:

- W3C Link Checker
- Xenu's link sleuth

But they couldn't capture dynamic website where the links are dynamically generated.

Any hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Screaming Frog](http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/) - it can crawl hashbang-ed urls:

[image: hashbang url]

http://www.deepcrawl.com and http://www.crawlajax.com promise to be able to it too.